# Debian Wheeze, install PHP extension

Tags: debian, apt-get, php-extension

Yes, i know, Debian Wheeze is out of the date.

But there is posibility install PHP extension with "apt-get"?

Maybe i need to use some others source list for expired LTS?

```
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php5 libtidy-0.99-0 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
Suggested packages:
  php-pear
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtidy-0.99-0 php5-tidy
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
8 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 218 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,273 kB of archives.
After this operation, 535 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?

WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  php5-cli libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-gd php5-common libtidy-0.99-0 php5-tidy
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?


Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main php5-cli i386 5.4.45-0+deb7u12
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main libapache2-mod-php5 i386 5.4.45-0+deb7u12
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main php5-mysql i386 5.4.45-0+deb7u12
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main php5-imap i386 5.4.45-0+deb7u12
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main php5-mcrypt i386 5.4.45-0+deb7u12
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main php5-curl i386 5.4.45-0+deb7u12
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main php5-gd i386 5.4.45-0+deb7u12
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main php5-common i386 5.4.45-0+deb7u12
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main libtidy-0.99-0 i386 20091223cvs-1.2+deb7u1
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main php5-tidy i386 5.4.45-0+deb7u12
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-cli_5.4.45-0+deb7u12_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/libapache2-mod-php5_5.4.45-0+deb7u12_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-mysql_5.4.45-0+deb7u12_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-imap_5.4.45-0+deb7u12_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-mcrypt_5.4.45-0+deb7u12_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-curl_5.4.45-0+deb7u12_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-gd_5.4.45-0+deb7u12_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-common_5.4.45-0+deb7u12_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/t/tidy/libtidy-0.99-0_20091223cvs-1.2+deb7u1_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-tidy_5.4.45-0+deb7u12_i386.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

My source list:

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that [Debian 7 (wheezy) is an obsolete stable release](https://www.debian.org/releases/) (emphasis on the obsolete).

I would recommended against you continuing to use it.

The error you are getting is simply the result of the release being obsolete and the repositories no longer being valid.

There are some efforts from the community to provide [Long Term Support](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) and [Extended Long Term Support](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Extended), but it would be best to make sure your use case really needs this.

The community effort to provide support for older releases is coordinated by [Frexian](https://www.freexian.com/services/debian-lts.html).

You could update your sources list to try to get LTS packages, but that would require you to verify exactly what packages you need vs the packages are being kept updated.

Is there a good enough reason you do not upgrade to more recent release?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be supported on Debian 7, but you could try to run these commands on a separate machine and copy them over:

```
apt-get download [package name]
```

Credit for this solution goes to https://askubuntu.com/questions/30482/is-there-an-apt-command-to-download-a-deb-file-from-the-repositories-to-the-curr

Then install the .deb file with

```
apt install ./[package name].deb
```

If not, upgrading is probably your only option.